# Eclipse Birt pass Data via Java

Tags: java, birt

I use Eclipse Birt to generate my reports. I call Birt from within Java. 
In Java I calculate my data and now want to push it directly to birt.

```
    List<String> values = new LinkedList<String>();
    values.add("a");
    values.add("b");
    values.add("c");

    IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);
    task.getAppContext().put("data", values);
    ...
    task.run();
```

I know that I must create a Datasource and a Dataset in Birt. But how can I now retrieve the data within Birt?

Comment: So, do you need to retrieve or to inject data?